# Getting error when trying to connect to SAPGUI using Pywin32

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, sap-gui

I am using this function to connect to SAPGUI:

```
def sap_connect(local_sap_box):
    SapGuiAuto = win32com.client.GetObject('SAPGUI')
    if not type(SapGuiAuto) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
        return
    application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
    if not type(application) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
        SapGuiAuto = None
        return
    connection = application.OpenConnection(local_sap_box,True)
    if not type(connection) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
        application = None
        SapGuiAuto = None
        return
    session = connection.Children(0)
    sap_box = session.findById('wnd[0]/sbar/pane[1]').text
    sap_box = sap_box[0:3]
    sap_sbar = session.findById('wnd[0]/sbar').text
    sap_user = sap_sbar[17:23]
    print('User ' + sap_user + ' logged into ' + sap_box)
    if not type(session) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
        connection = None
        application = None
        SapGuiAuto = None
        return
    return session
```

Since today I get a 'com_error: (-2147221020, 'Invalid syntax', None, None)' error.

This is the full error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
com_error                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-1c5ab2335269> in <module>
      9 for order_group in order_groups:
     10     for sap_box, currency_settings in order_groups[order_group].items():
---> 11         sap_session = sap_connect(sap_box)
     12         sap_RPX0(sap_session, currency_settings)
     13         kob1 = sap_KOB1(sap_session, order_group, '07/01/2021', '06/30/2022', 'ID_KOB1_ALL')

<ipython-input-2-9c51187610f0> in sap_connect(local_sap_box)
      1 def sap_connect(local_sap_box):
----> 2     SapGuiAuto = win32com.client.GetObject('SAPGUI')
      3     if not type(SapGuiAuto) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
      4         return
      5     application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py in GetObject(Pathname, Class, clsctx)
     70     return GetActiveObject(Class, clsctx)
     71   else:
---> 72     return Moniker(Pathname, clsctx)
     73 
     74 def GetActiveObject(Class, clsctx = pythoncom.CLSCTX_ALL):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py in Moniker(Pathname, clsctx)
     85     Python friendly version of GetObject's moniker functionality.
     86   """
---> 87   moniker, i, bindCtx = pythoncom.MkParseDisplayName(Pathname)
     88   dispatch = moniker.BindToObject(bindCtx, None, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
     89   return __WrapDispatch(dispatch, Pathname, clsctx=clsctx)

com_error: (-2147221020, 'Invalid syntax', None, None)
```

I am using SSO, the SAPGUI Logon Pad is 760. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is significantly after the fact, but I hope that this answer is useful to someone.

Here is what I have found to fix this problem. I ran into this same issue trying this same idea. Here is my version of your sap_connect().

```
import win32com.client

def connect_sap():
    SapGuiAuto = win32com.client.GetObject("SAPGUI")
    app = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
    connection = app.Children(0)
    session = connection.Children(0)
    session.findById('wnd[0]').maximize
```

Calling this function I get the following error message.

```
com_error                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [78], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 test4.connect_sap()

Input In [71], in SapGui.connect_sap(self)
     12 def connect_sap(self):
---> 13     SapGuiAuto = win32com.client.GetObject("SAPGUI")
     14     app = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
     15     self.connection = app.Children(0)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py:85, in 
GetObject(Pathname, Class, clsctx)
     83     return GetActiveObject(Class, clsctx)
     84 else:
---> 85     return Moniker(Pathname, clsctx)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py:102, in 
Moniker(Pathname, clsctx)
     98 def Moniker(Pathname, clsctx=pythoncom.CLSCTX_ALL):
     99     """
    100     Python friendly version of GetObject's moniker functionality.
    101     """
--> 102     moniker, i, bindCtx = pythoncom.MkParseDisplayName(Pathname)
    103     dispatch = moniker.BindToObject(bindCtx, None, 
pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
    104     return __WrapDispatch(dispatch, Pathname, clsctx=clsctx)

com_error: (-2147221020, 'Invalid syntax', None, None)
```

Inserting this function worked for me. I found that the function to connect to SAP requires the SAP GUI program to be opened prior to calling that function.

```
import subprocess 

def open_sap(self):
  path = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe'
  subprocess.Popen(path)
```

So, in the end I call the open_sap() function, then I can call the connect_sap() function. You can also call the connect_sap() function if the SAP GUI is already open (which isn't as helpful, as I find I exit out of it as soon as I am done.

I hope this helps!